# Остановить flash (музыка) javascript

Tags: flash, javascript

Суть вопроса: на странице есть два видеоплеера, и один плеер с фоновой музыкой, при клике по видеоплееру нужно остановить музыку. Можно ли такое реализировать? И если можно, то как?

Пациент http://prob.obmenniki.pp.ua/

P.S.: Скажу честно, в javascript полный ноль, а сделать нужно (((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно обращаться из ActionScript к JavaScript и обратно через класс ExternalInterface. На сайте Adobe, помимо описания класса, как обычно, есть и примеры реализации (смотрите "Дополнительные примеры"):

[ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/ru_RU/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html)